# Cannot intercept outgoing AJAX request from page using Testcafe

Tags: javascript, request, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am attempting to use TestCafe for a client-side javascript library, and I am unable to capture any outgoing AJAX requests for on the load of a testing page through the counting mechanism.

My attempts involve using the [`RequestLogger`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html) object from this library involve setting up the first parameter using the regex `/\.org/`, to capture any outgoing tile request which uses the .org suffix. I believe this makes sense, as all the outgoing requests go to openstreetmap.org with the aim of grabbing png map tiles.

The core of my test looks like the following:

```
import { RequestLogger } from "testcafe";

fixture`Hello World - Leaflet`.page`http://localhost:8080`;

const logger = RequestLogger(/org/, {
  logRequestHeaders: true,
  logResponseHeaders: true
});

test("Test if there's an outgoing network request...", async t => {
  // Do something...
  await t
    .wait(5000)
    .expect(logger.count(() => true))
    .gt(0, "Must detect more than zero outgoing requests to openstreetmap");
});
```

Is there something I am missing in order to capture the proper outgoing count of AJAX requests?

If it helps, I've made a repo which contains this problem, set up in a way that people can attempt to solve without configuration:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your detailed description.

You need to [attach](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/attaching-hooks-to-tests-and-fixtures.html) the `logger` to your `test`/`fixture`. You can also attach and detach hooks during test run using the `t.addRequestHooks` and `t.removeRequestHooks` methods.

In the test code, I attached the `logger` hook to the `test`:

```
import { RequestLogger } from "testcafe";

fixture`Hello World - Leaflet`.page`http://localhost:8080`;

const logger = RequestLogger(/org/);

test
    .requestHooks(logger)
    ("Test if there's an outgoing network request...", async t => {
        await t
            .wait(5000)
            .expect(logger.count(() => true))
            .gt(0, "Must detect more than zero outgoing requests to openstreetmap");
    });
```